# Unittest or Pytest for Discord Bot

Tags: python, discord.py, pytest

Writing Unittests/Pytests

I have a discord bot and I'm trying to write tests for it. I tried a library called distest and it worked well for certain things but not all..

I have a second bot that sends a message and checks the response, but it's just not working with Unittests or Pytest.

Here's an example of one of my tests,
it's checking for the reply "Pong!" if "ping" was sent.

I run my bot that needs to be tested before calling the script with pytest

```
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import pytest

TOKEN = "bot token of tester bot"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?/')
bot.run(TOKEN)
target_id = "ID of bot to be tested"
channel_id = "ID of channel of where it will be tested"

async def test_ping():
    correct_response = 'Pong!'
    channel = await bot.fetch_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send("ping")

    def check(m):
        return m.content == correct_response and m.author.id == target_id

    response = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    assert (response.content == correct_response)
```

Pytests is stuck on collecting and when I tried Unittests it just hung and did nothing

Answer (score 0):

You did try to register the ping command after running the bot. `bot.run(TOKEN)` must be end of the code. Also you must put a decorator to resgistering command. So the code will be this:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import pytest

TOKEN = "bot token of tester bot"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?/')
target_id = "ID of bot to be tested"
channel_id = "ID of channel of where it will be tested"

@bot.command(name="ping") #if name did not entered, function name will be the command name
async def test_ping(ctx): #Every command takes context object as first parameter
    correct_response = 'Pong!'
    channel = await bot.fetch_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send("ping")

    def check(m):
        return m.content == correct_response and m.author.id == target_id

    response = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    assert (response.content == correct_response)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

---

Basicly context object:

```
await ctx.send("message") #sends message to command's invoked channel.
ctx.guild #returns server if not channel is a DM channel
ctx.channel #returns channel
ctx.author #returns message's author
ctx.message #returns message
ctx.message.content #returns the messsge's content
```

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm asking. I'm trying to test my bot not run it with a command. I have a bot running already and the second bot will be trying to test it with these tests using pytest